# multiple object notification message by google

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I was copying few files of < 10MB size individually to bucket located in EU location from a US physical location using gsutil cp command. I received multiple object notification message for the same file. These multiple object notification had the same size, md5sum but different x-goof-message-number. Not all files or any specific file had multiple object notification, but this happened randomly for any file.

To eliminate the possibility of gsutil resumable transfer as culprit, I had set resumable_threshold to 15MB in .boto file.

Let me know what may be cause of multiple object notification. Multiple object notification for the same object is erroneous event for my application.

This is strange as this is not seen while the same operation is done for bucket located in US location.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [Object Change Notification](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Reliable_Delivery) documentation:

> Note: Because of the retry mechanism above, it is possible that
>   notifications are delivered more than once. Ensure that your
>   application is idempotent with respect to processing a unique
>   notification.

However, the `X-Goog-Message-Number` header should be the same if you receive multiple notifications. Are you receiving multiple notifications for the same event with different `X-Goog-Message-Number` values? Are you sure you didn't create multiple notification channels? You can tell if two messages are part of the same notification channel by looking at the `X-Goog-Channel-Id` header.

Comment: I confirm this that the X-goog-message-number were different

Comment: what about X-Goog-Channel-Id ?

Comment: Also, is the file large? gsutil will use automatic parallel composite uploads for large files

Comment: I confirm this that the X-goog-message-number were different,both the messages were having same channel-id,  both the messages were having different timestamp though, "updated":"2014-03-10T09:57:12.007Z", "updated":"2014-03-10T09:57:02.255Z". Both the messages have same md5sum, crc32, stag. The file size was exact 10MB, with resumable threshold set to 15MB

Comment: Are they both EXISTS messages?

Comment: They both are exists messages. This is a reproducible event, let me know if there is debugging setting in gsutil that can be enabled to get more insight on this.

Comment: Could you send your channel id and the contents of the two messages to gs-team@google.com?